# Need a macro to search and update the record from one worksheet to another

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I need a macro code to search the content(it may be numeric or aplhanumeric) from sheet1 in the cell 1 to 1000 and to search the same text from sheet2. and if it founds then i need to update the content corresponding  to adjacent cell.
eg:

```
sheet1
1024     D
505A
6057     C




sheet2
1024     D
6057     C
```

Comment: So does sheet 2 end up looking like sheet 1 except that the rows with nothing in the 2nd column (no D or C or etc) have been deleted?  Or are you saying that Sheet 2 started out with no letters in column 2, and your macro puts whatever letter it found next to 1024 in sheet 1, next to 1024 in sheet 2?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the look up values are in column A and the value to copy is in column B.

```
Sub FindValues()

Dim lookUpSheet As Worksheet, updateSheet As Worksheet
Dim valueToSearch As String
Dim i As Integer, t As Integer

Set lookUpSheet = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set updateSheet = Worksheets("sheet2")

'get the number of the last row with data in sheet1 and in sheet2
lastRowLookup = lookUpSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowUpdate = updateSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'for every value in column A of sheet2
For i = 1 To lastRowUpdate
     valueToSearch = updateSheet.Cells(i, 1)
     'look the value in column A of sheet1
     For t = 1 To lastRowLookup
        'if found a match, copy column B value to sheet1 and proceed to the next value
        If lookUpSheet.Cells(t, 1) = valueToSearch Then
            updateSheet.Cells(i, 2) = lookUpSheet.Cells(t, 2)
            Exit For
        End If
     Next t
Next i

End Sub
```