# How to update existing data from Sheet1 to Sheet2 using Macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I just want to ask if someone do have a code for this.
I have a saved data in Sheet2 and I want to update it using the new data from Sheet1. In the below example, the code will search for Family "Oh" in Sheet2 and update its details using the updated information from Sheet1 when I click on the Update button. Here are the screenshots of

Sheet1:

[image: Sheet1]

and

Sheet2:

[image: Sheet2]

Tried this code but I can't get it to work correctly

```
Sub FindValues()

Dim lookUpSheet As Worksheet, updateSheet As Worksheet
Dim valueToSearch As String
Dim i As Integer, t As Integer

Set lookUpSheet = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set updateSheet = Worksheets("sheet2")

'get the number of the last row with data in sheet1 and in sheet2
lastRowLookup = lookUpSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastRowUpdate = updateSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'for every value in column A of sheet2
For i = 1 To lastRowUpdate
 valueToSearch = updateSheet.Cells(i, 1)
 'look the value in column A of sheet1
 For t = 1 To lastRowLookup
    'if found a match, copy column B value to sheet1 and proceed to the next value
    If lookUpSheet.Cells(t, 1) = valueToSearch Then
        updateSheet.Cells(i, 2) = lookUpSheet.Cells(t, 2)
        Exit For
    End If
 Next t
 Next i

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Did you at least **try** amending the code to reflect the fact that you want to match on 3 columns (or, at least, I assume you do) and the fact that you want to update column D, not column B?  If so, please post the code that you tried.

Comment: That was the original code from this site also, i tried amending it but it only updates 1 info per column. Means it will update 11 to all of Family Oh in column D instead of 11, 12, 13, 15

Comment: Did you at least try amending the code to reflect the fact that you want to match on 3 columns, i.e. did you try checking whether all of the three columns (A, B, and C) matched, or did you expect that that would automatically happen just because you checked column A?

Comment: You really shouldn't just copy/paste [someone else's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28918966/6535336) (especially without attribution) and say that you "can't get it to work correctly" when you have made Zero effort at getting it to work correctly.

Comment: yes I tried amending it and like I said the results were not as what I have expected. I tried to change the columns A B C but same result. I just saw that answer and tried that code. I worked only on a single search and replace but if the table contains more than one searchable items, it will only replace all of the info with the same data. So if I ran the macro, instead of having Age 11, 12, 13, 15 in column D, it will replace the Age as 11, 11, 11, 11 :) It would be much appreciated if there is an alternative code that is much easier than that since this is my first time working on excel vba

Comment: That original code that I searched in this site is working perfectly, but only to a single search and replace process and I am still figuring out on how to make it work in a multiple data update :) Oh btw, thank you for editing my post I appreciate it a lot :)

Comment: I can try to upload and share the link of the actual sheet that I am working here for reference

Comment: Why don't you make an attempt at changing the `If` to check three values instead of just one, and post your code - then people will be more inclined to help you.  (At the moment, the only effort you have shown is a search to find a piece of code somewhat similar, and then post a question saying "this isn't close enough - please finish it for me".  People don't like answering those sort of questions.  But show a **bit** of effort and people will **gladly** fix the problems you encounter.)

Comment: The data in your question seems clear enough - I could easily make the one line change (two lines if you include the change of "2" to "4") needed now, but we need to see you make an effort yourself.

Comment: I am still working on the code right now. Amending it and testing :) I'll delete this question once I got the code working correctly

Comment: If you **don't** get it working correctly, feel free to ask a new question (or even edit this one if you like - we can delete all the comment history) and we will be happy to help you fix anything **you** get wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you expect, I've commented the code so you may understand what it is doing:

```
Sub FindValues()
    Dim lookUpSheet As Worksheet, updateSheet As Worksheet
    Dim valueToSearch As String
    Dim i As Long, t As Long

    Set lookUpSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set updateSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    lastRowLookup = lookUpSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowUpdate = updateSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'get the number of the last row with data in sheet1 and in sheet2

    For i = 2 To lastRowLookup 'i = 2 to last to omit the first row as that row is for headers

        valueFamily = lookUpSheet.Cells(i, 1) 'Family, 1 = Column A
        valueDOB = lookUpSheet.Cells(i, 2) 'DOB, 2 = Column  B
        valueName = lookUpSheet.Cells(i, 3) 'Name, 3 = Column C
        valueAge = lookUpSheet.Cells(i, 4) 'Age, 4 = Column D
        'above get the values from the four column into variables

        For t = 2 To lastRowUpdate 't = 2 to last to omit the first row as that row is for headers
            If updateSheet.Cells(t, 1) = valueFamily And updateSheet.Cells(t, 2) = valueDOB And updateSheet.Cells(t, 3) = valueName Then
            'if family, dob and name match, then
            updateSheet.Cells(t, 4) = valueAge
            'update age value
            Exit For
            End If
        Next t
    Next i
End Sub
```

This could be shortened without using the variables and comparing cells instead like below:

```
Sub FindValues()
    Dim lookUpSheet As Worksheet, updateSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, t As Long

    Set lookUpSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set updateSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    lastRowLookup = lookUpSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowUpdate = updateSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'get the number of the last row with data in sheet1 and in sheet2

    For i = 2 To lastRowLookup 'i = 2 to last to omit the first row as that row is for headers
        For t = 2 To lastRowUpdate 't = 2 to last to omit the first row as that row is for headers
            If updateSheet.Cells(t, 1) = lookUpSheet.Cells(i, 1) And updateSheet.Cells(t, 2) = lookUpSheet.Cells(i, 2) And updateSheet.Cells(t, 3) = lookUpSheet.Cells(i, 3) Then
            'if family, dob and name match, then
            updateSheet.Cells(t, 4) = lookUpSheet.Cells(i, 4)
            'update age value
            Exit For
            End If
        Next t
    Next i
End Sub
```

The issue you were having is from the fact that you needed to have the IF Statement look at the first 3 cells instead of a single value, so with the AND between conditions you compare all three.

Comment: Wow! This is the kind of explanation I have been looking for. I now see the error. So that's why I can't get the code to work correctly even if I amend the codes because I was too focused on having the macro to look for the Family Name and overwrite the info instead of having it look at the first 3 cells. Thank you so much this really helps a lot and I really appreciate it. I have been amending the codes for 5 days now and searching the web for possible formula to make it work but I still can't get it to work on my end. I really need a lot of things to learn regarding this excel thing :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how to update to sql using adodb.

```
Sub UpdateSQL()

    Dim Cn As Object
    Dim strConn As String, Name As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim vDB

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
    Set Ws = Sheets(1)
    Name = Sheets(2).Name
    With Ws
        vDB = .Range("a2", .Range("d" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    Set Cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Cn.Open strConn

    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        strSQL = "UPDATE [" & Name & "$] set Age=" & vDB(i, 4) & " where Family = '" & vDB(i, 1) & "' AND DOB =#" & vDB(i, 2) & "# AND Name='" & vDB(i, 3) & "' "
        Cn.Execute strSQL
    Next i

    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I will try this code on my next form so that I can have an idea on how to make it work with adodb. I still have plenty of forms left and will select if which form needs an adodb or just a simple table for my database :)